# Booting Win7 64bit from USB 3.0 thumb drive - is it possible to use the 3.0 speeds?

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, bsod, usb-3

As it sits it takes 4-6 minutes to load a web page using my USB 2.0 slot.

My Thumb Drive(PSF32GTAB3USB) is 3.0 and I have a port on my laptop (N53SV) that's also USB 3.0.

However, if I try booting to it I get a BSOD with a stop code that references the kernel.

I thought this would be a cool project but I haven't been able to find anything on this issue. Anyone here tried this before and know what has to be done? BIOS is completely up to date.

Comment: What stop code do you get? Where, precisely, in the booting process does it happen?

Comment: The problem is your trying to do this with Windows 7.  Windows 7 does not support USB 3 devices at the stage your trying to use one at.

Comment: have you added the USB3.0 driver into the BOOT and Install.wim?

Comment: @magicandre1981 - If he did it would work :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your Windows installation on a USB 3.0 storage device by using the following guide created by [whs](https://superuser.com/users/7105/whs).  This same guide according to the author can be used for any version of Windows 7 and Windows 8.x.

> Step 1 - Check the speed of your USB stick
>
> To measure the speed of your stick I recommend HD Tune. It provides
>   data regarding the data transfer rate and the access time.

[image]

> Step 2 - Download the WAIK and extract the imagex file
>
> If you do not have the WAIK (Windows Automated Installation Kit) on
>   your system, then you have to download from [this Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5753).
>
> Then you have to copy the **imagex.exe**. You find that in **C:\Program
>   Files\Windows AIK\Tools**. There is a 32bit version and a 64-bit version.

[image]

> You choose 32-bit when you install a 32-bit version of Windows 10 on
>   your stick - 64-bit when you install the 64-bit version. Copy the the
>   imagex.exe ​that corresponds to your `Windows 10.iso` to the desktop.

> Step 3 - Mount the `Windows 10.iso` in a virtual BD ROM
>
> We first have to create a virtual BD ROM with the [Virtual Clone Drive
>   Program](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html). Download, install and run this program. It is very simple.

[image]

> To mount the `Windows 10.iso` into the BD ROM, follow the instructions in the next picture. Make sure you remember the drive letter of the BD ROM (in my
>   case 'H:') because you will need that later.

[image]

> We now have to define a primary active partition on the USB stick. For
>   that we open an elevated Command Prompt (run as administrator). Type
>   or paste each of the following commands (one by one) and hit Enter
>   after each command.

```
Diskpart
List disk
Select disk n (where n is the number that was given for your stick in List disk)
Clean
Create partition primary
Format fs=ntfs quick
Assign
Active
Exit
```

> Your stick is now ready for the installation of Windows 10.
>
> Step 5 - Install Windows 10 on the stick
>
> This is very easy now with a command in Command Prompt. It may take a
>   little while to transfer the whole system, so be patient. The Command
>   is:

```
"C:\Users\Your Name\Desktop\imagex.exe" /apply H:\sources\install.wim 1 F:\
```

> Your Name is the name of your system. H: is the letter of my BD ROM
>   (step 3). If your BD ROM has another letter, you have to change that
>   accordingly. F: is the drive letter of my stick (step 4). Here you
>   also have to replace it if your stick is on another letter.
>
> As last step you have to run a command to install the boot files.

```
bcdboot F:\windows /s F:
```

> Here again F: is the letter for my stick which you may have to adjust.
>
> Step 6 - Run Windows 10 from your USB stick
>
> **The first thing you will have to do is the Windows 10 normal installation. During this process, Microsoft requires a check number
>   which they will send you to your email. Therefore make sure you have
>   access to your email from another device.**
>
> When you are done with the installation, you can run Windows 10 from
>   your stick. For that you have to change the boot sequence in the BIOS
>   pointing at the USB stick as first boot device.

[Here is the source for this guide](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3373-windows-10-setup-run-usb-flash-drive.html#post175689)

Comment: I only submitted this answer in attempt to get the relevant information on this website instead of on an external website.  All the credit goes to [whs](http://superuser.com/users/7105/whs)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica - The answer applies to Windows 7.  I indicated that was the case in the first sentence. The original author, submitted an answer which was only a link, 5 years ago I submitted this answer to include the steps from the source material. **They are the author of the tutorial on the external website.**